# How to queue multiple pygame scripts in a module?

Tags: python, time, queue, pygame

Does anyone know if there is a way to make pygame scripts run one after another?
This is my module below, I would like to know if I could get them to deploy at certain intervals, that is, I would like 'A_long_time_ago' to run, last for 5 seconds then close and immediately load 'sounds' and 'logo', then 3 seconds later for them to close, transitioning into 'Title_Crawl'.

#### The Module

```
from A_long_time_ago import *
from sounds import *
from logo import *
from Title_Crawl import *
```

#### A_long_time_ago

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1376, 760))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

font = pygame.font.SysFont("franklingothicbook", 40)

text = font.render("A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away....", True,         (75, 213, 238))


while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text,
        (700 - text.get_width() // 2, 380 - text.get_height() // 2))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

#### sounds

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('The_Theme.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

#### logo

```
    import pygame
    import os

    _image_library = {}
    def get_image(path):
            global _image_library
            image = _image_library.get(path)
            if image == None:
                    canonicalized_path = path.replace('/', os.sep).replace('\\', os.sep)
                    image = pygame.image.load(canonicalized_path)
                    _image_library[path] = image
            return image

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
    done = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            done = True

            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

            screen.blit(get_image('sw.png'), (10, 10))

            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
```

#### Title_Crawl

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Title Crawl')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
screen_r = screen.get_rect()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("franklingothicdemibold", 40)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def main():

    crawl = ["Star Wars - The Wilds"," ","It is  a dark time for the Galaxy. The evil Dark","Lord, Vitiate is rising to power. Alone, a single", "spec   is  on  a  trip,  a  trip that will ultimately", "rectify  the wrongs of the galaxy. The keepers ", "of  peace are dying out and the  DARK SIDE is", "lurking,   a   conniving   force   determined  to", "become the omniarch."]

    texts = []
    # we render the text once, since it's easier to work with surfaces
    # also, font rendering is a performance killer
    for i, line in enumerate(crawl):
        s = font.render(line, 1, (229, 177, 58))
        # we also create a Rect for each Surface. 
        # whenever you use rects with surfaces, it may be a good idea to use sprites instead
        # we give each rect the correct starting position 
        r = s.get_rect(centerx=screen_r.centerx, y=screen_r.bottom + i * 45)
        texts.append((r, s))

    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT or e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                return

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        for r, s in texts:
            # now we just move each rect by one pixel each frame
            r.move_ip(0, -1)
            # and drawing is as simple as this
            screen.blit(s, r)

        # if all rects have left the screen, we exit
        if not screen_r.collidelistall([r for (r, _) in texts]):
            return

        # only call this once so the screen does not flicker
        pygame.display.flip()

        # cap framerate at 60 FPS
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to make them into classes and give them a run method, and then instantiate each one on a timer and call its run method to do what it needs to do.

Comment: How do I do this? I understand that I need to use OO programming but I don't fully understand that?